# how to make an interactive video with clickable buttons on it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

how to make an interactive video with clickable buttons on it? when we click on each button a different clip will be played. do we need to do it in HTML CSS and javascript, or it needs to be designed through different software and then integrate into landing page .

here is the example url , it will show buttons after 3 to 4 minutes and when we click each button different video clip will get play.
https://www.codworkshop.com/training/?utm_source=website&utm_term=cdwtraining
.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I built https://www.Stornaway.io as a no-code web app for this to let people easily design branching interactive videos and then embed an HTML/JavaScript player on any site.

You can design & playtest with the trial, then to publish it's paid because of hosting and streaming costs. Or you can export what you've made in Stornaway to native mobile/desktop/VR apps via our Unity plugin, or to interactive YouTube via a Chrome extension.

For simple YouTube videos with links to other YouTube videos, you can just add links to the end of YouTube videos with End Screens.

Other web-based interactive video apps are available with different button features & costs. H5P lets you do host-your-own interactive stuff with custom code.

You mention links after 3-4 mins. From a lot of experience, I recommend that you show links sooner than 3 to 4 minutes – when people know they are playing an interactive video, they get impatient to get on with the interactivity and see it regularly.

Stornaway will let you design & playtest for free to get a feel for this user experience, whatever you end up using.